# What natural substance can I use to up the pH balance?

Tags: soil, soil-amendment, ph

What can be used as a natural pH up substance for my medical marijuana plants water? I have them growing in soil & have been using citrus powder to lower my ph.

Comment: Define "natural"

Comment: Are you trying to make the water more acid or more alkaline?

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to do,PH up or PH down.and please post the PH and hardness of your tap water.

Comment: look for "cal" at a mexican grocery store; fine white powdered calcium. ashes (wood/charcoal) are a strong base as well, though you will need to filter the mixture if you're growing them hydroponically.